# Jenkins on a Docker unable to clone repository from GitLab, returned status code 128

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, automated-tests, gitlab

**Jenkins that runs on Docker trow `returned status code 128` after trying to clone remote repo on self-hosted GitLaB**

[image: Jenkins on a Docker unable to clone / fetch repository from GitLab returned status code 128]

**My setup**

- Cent OS
- Docekr version: 18.06.0-ce
- Jenkins: 2.121.2 , 2.146 ,

**Steps to I setup Jenkins**

1. Create container with volume `docker run -it --name jenkins -p 8080:8080 --mount source=jenkins_vol,target=/var/jenkins_home IageId`
2. Install suggested plugins.
3. Go to volime under jenkins user, create SSH key.
4. Added public key to the GitLAb
5. Run `ssh -T git@gitlab.domain.com` from the volume to enetiate connection. Works Ok.
6. Create Freestyle project
7. Added repo url `git@gitlab.domain.com:ProjectName/automated-testing-qa.git` to freestyle project
8. Added private key and pass phrase to Jenkins. 
   When run Jenkins build it tries to clone repo for ~10-15min and than fails with the message you see above.

When instead of SSH URL I use https URL it also fails.

Comment: Could you try to clone outside Jenkins? Also could you try to clone a public github URL instead private self hosted gitlab?   Maybe the error is not related to yu your Jenkins.

Comment: Cloning outside Jenkins works ok. I didn't try to clone a public repo, I will give it a try.

Comment: Maybe is not possible access to your gitlab host from jenkins host. Please perform a ping, curl, ssh test from commandline from inside of jenkins host, not with jenkins ui.

Comment: Above in my setup steps I described that I performed test from the Jenkins host and it was successful. "5. Run ssh -T git@gitlab.domain.com from the volume to initiate connection. Works Ok"

Comment: I was able to clone public GitLab repository, so seems like something wrong on my side. Bu Jenkins on my laptop works ok with that private repo, I'm working with it each day.

Comment: This comment in a GitLab plugin page "**The credentials for cloning (usually SSH credentials) should be configured separately, in the git plugin.**" gave me a hint that issue is in a wrong configuration of default git plugin. `Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration` in Jenkins on a laptop "Path to Git executable" set to `git`. Cloning with this config was working, so I changed it to `/usr/bin/git` to see will it fail cloning. It actually failed cloning same way (with 128 error) I have on Jenkins on my server!

Comment: What's interesting when I changed config back to `git` it still failing, so I broke my only working Jenkins instance  Actually it broke only one job other jobs runs ok. It's very weird!

Comment: Cloning inside a docker container requires special treatment :S

Comment: You were able to clone a public repository using your jenkins configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to clone your repo using SSH URL from within the docker container directly ? Does it work ?

When you use HTTPS URL does it not prompt you for a password ? Try cloning your repo using HTTPS URL from within docker container, this should prompt you for the password and see if it works when you give the correct password ?

Please post your attempts output here so we can see what is going on.

Comment: Yes, besides running a test from within the docker container I also tried to clone the private repo from the same company site and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue simply by using **SSH key without passphrase**.

When you generate SSH pare just hit enter when it's asking you to enter passphrase. 
Then in Jenkins credentials when setting private SSH key just skip passphrase field.

I also noticed that when I used the same credential setup and just edited values Issue still occurred. So, make sure to create new set of credentials for private SSH with no passphrase, don't reuse already existed one.

Comment: No wonder! I did read that `Jenkins does not support passphrases for SSH keys` when setting up my own SSH key few months ago but did not remember in time to help you sorry!

Comment: I don't get why do they haw passphrase option if it doesn't work?!